# How to avoid request to Java Web Application servlet from outside some network?

Tags: java, servlets, filter

I am trying to build a web application which is only meant to be accessed from inside a specific network, lets say a company's network. If anyone tries the URL for the application from outside the company's network then the access should be denied. I know I can use `doFilter` method for this task. But I am not really sure how to start checking the requests that are only coming from inside the company's network.

Can anyone point me to any useful resource or tell me how to achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

try to implement

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                 FilterChain filterChain)  throws IOException, ServletException {

String validParams = request.getParameter("validParams");

if(!"blockTheRequest".equals(validParams)){
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}

HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse) httpResponse;
httpResponse.getWriter().write("a different response... e.g in HTML");
}
```

and you need do configure it with in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>yourFilterURL</filter-name>
    <filter-class>servlets.SimpleServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilterURL</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.pattern</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Your answer will only avoid those requests in which the client doesn't provide `validparams`. It won't avoid the requests from outside the company's network if `validparams` is valid